# Series with Comparison Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check the convergence of $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n+3\over n^4-1}$$

I think the comparison test is useful.

Compare this to ${n\over n^4} = {1\over n^3}$. I'm not sure though.

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable to me! Have you tried yet?

Comment: $\frac{\frac{n+3}{n^4-1}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}=\frac{n^4+3n^3}{n^4-1}=\frac{1-3/n}{1-1/n^4}\to1$

Comment: I want to know if ${n+3\over n^4-1}\le {1\over n^3}$. I don't see it.

Comment: @graydad That was not ratio test.

Comment: @Pp.. What is the technique you're using in your first comment?

Comment: @Gino [Comparison test v2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test). New features: Often easier to handle than [Comparison test v1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For all $n\geq 2$,

$$n^4 - 1 \geq \dfrac{1}{2}n^4$$

and for all $n \geq 3$,

$$
n + 3 \leq 2n.
$$

The general idea here is that the beginning of the sequence doesn't affect convergence, and that $\sum ca_n$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ does, so you can get rid of $-1$ and $+3$ by comparing to relevant multiples of $n, n^4$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That comparison will not work. As $\frac{n+3}{n^4-1} \geq \frac{1}{n^3}$

Comment: Depends what you call comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{n+3}{n^4-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k+4}{k^4+4k^3+6k^2+4k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k+4}{k^4+4k^3}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}=\zeta(3).$$

Answer (score 0):

By the [Limit Comparison Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtbZZiSLemQ) we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{n+3}{n^4-1}}{\frac{1}{n^3}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{3}{n}}{1 - \frac{1}{n^4}} = 1$$

As $0 < 1 < \infty$ then either both series converge or both diverge. Then you may use your idea.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {n+3}{{n}^{4}-1}\lt \frac{2n}{{n}^{3}} = \frac{2} {{n}^{2}}$$
for n large enough, thus converges